# Dataframe into S3 Bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am trying to put data into some sort of database. My company currently uses S3 and not a relational DB (which I am used to). I did some googling and found that you can insert a dataframe into S3. I am having trouble because I am looking at this as a columns and fields way. A dataframe has columns, fields, AND an INDEX (Medical, arrest, offender, jail).

Question: Would having an index work so I can then query and get results that I need like let's say, I want to get all Medical, arrest, offender, and Jail from ONLY bucket2?

```
    current dataframe:

                 bucket1     bucket2      bucket 3
    Medical        1          3              5
    Arrest         2          6              14
    Offender       9          11             11
    Jail           14         22             1
```

I was thinking of reading my excel sheet with the data and convert to dataframe then insert the dataframe to S3

```
  # import pandas as pd
    import pandas as pd
    import os  
    import openpyxl

    path = r'C:/Reports'
    filename = 'scraper_report.xlsx'

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(path, filename))
    ws = wb['Totals_Summary']

    data_rows = []
    for row in ws['A2':'E15']:
        data_cols = []
        for cell in row:
            data_cols.append(cell.value)
        data_rows.append(data_cols)
    print(data_rows)

    from io import StringIO # python3; python2: BytesIO 
    import boto3

    bucket = 'my_bucket_name' # already created on S3
    csv_buffer = StringIO()
    df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3_resource.Object(bucket, 'df.csv').put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

Comment: i actually use the DataFrame quite often for doing this kind of thing simply because it is convenient. So the answer is Yes...

Answer (score 1):

In terms of Excel to PD Dataframe, you can do it multiple ways.

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('path_to_file.xls')
df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet2')


There are 3 options:
1.  Read the first sheet directly into dataframe
2.  Read the excel file and get a list of sheets. Then chose and load the sheets.
3.  Read all sheets and store it in a dictionary.

Code Sample:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('excel_file_path.xls')
# this will read the first sheet into df

xls = pd.ExcelFile('excel_file_path.xls')

# Now you can list all sheets in the file
xls.sheet_names
# ['house', 'house_extra', ...]

# to read just one sheet to dataframe:
df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheetname="house")

# to read all sheets to a map
sheet_to_df_map = {}
for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names:
    sheet_to_df_map[sheet_name] = xls.parse(sheet_name)
Update:
# @ihightower pointed out in the comments that all sheets can be 
# directly read into an ordered dictionary in 1 step

# for pandas version >= 0.21.0
sheet_to_df_map = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=None)

# for pandas version < 0.21.0
sheet_to_df_map = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheetname=None)
```

In terms of going from Dataframe to S3 bucket, again, you can do a few different ways.

```
import awswrangler as wr
wr.s3.to_csv(
    df=df,
    path="s3://...",
)


Also...
    

import pandas as pd
df.to_csv("s3://my-test-bucket/sample.csv")


Also...


from io import StringIO 
import boto3

#Creating Session With Boto3.
session = boto3.Session(
aws_access_key_id='<your_access_key_id>',
aws_secret_access_key='<your_secret_access_key>'
)

#Creating S3 Resource From the Session.
s3_res = session.resource('s3')
csv_buffer = StringIO()
df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
bucket_name = 'stackvidhya'
s3_object_name = 'df.csv'
s3_res.Object(bucket_name, s3_object_name).put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())    
print("Dataframe is saved as CSV in S3 bucket.")
```

You will find a few more, similar, ideas here.

https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.s3.to_csv.html